# url parameter not alerting out in jQuery Mobile script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, parameter-passing

After clicking on an article link in my first html page, the URL of the second page looks like this:

localhost/basket/newstext.html?url=http://www.basket-planet.com/ru/news/9235

In JS, I'm trying to get the url=... and do something with it.  Here's what I have for the scripts:

page2.html:

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="newstext">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="textcontent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="js/newstext.js"></script>
</body>
```

newstext.js:

```
$('#newstext').bind('pageshow', function(event) {
var url = getUrlVars()["url"];
alert (url);
});

function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
```

If you need to see my first page along with js and php file, let me know.  Strange thing is I had it working before and now...I don't know what happened.  I tried placing the script between the head tags, doesn't work.  What's wrong here?

Comment: Is it the space between alert and the params? try alert(url)

Comment: That wasn't it...still nothing.

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, I recently created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which may help you out.